# Using .val to populate textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm currently trying to populate a text area with values from multiple inputs as they are typed, my problem is everytime I go to a new input, it clears the previous information from the text area and adds the new, is there anyway I can keep the information from previous fields and also add new info.

html

```
<input type="text" name="fname" ><br>
<input type="text" name="lname"><br>

<textarea type="text" id="content"></textarea><br>
```

jQuery

```
  $("input").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#content").text(value);
  }).keyup();
```

Codepen
http://codepen.io/michael52/pen/uzeqs

Comment: you should tell how the final result in the `textarea`should look like. if it should be combined you could do: `var value = $("[name='fname']").val()+" "+$("[name='lname']").val();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you build the textarea's content based on the other two boxes, not the old value of the textarea:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br>

<textarea type="text" id="content"></textarea><br>
```

JS:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
  var value = $('#fname').val() + ' ' + $('#lname').val();
  $("#content").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

Comment: "Well - no part of your code says that it should keep the old input." Of course not. If it did they wouldn't have a problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to append the new content, rather than replacing the old content:

```
$("#content").text(function(_, oldText) {
    return oldText + value;
});
```

Comment: Actually no, this creates duplicate content.

Comment: While this is the correct answer to the question, I think that he actually never wanted to append in the first place. The linked application wouldn't work properly if it was really appended.

Comment: @mdsl Quite possible. I went from what they said about wanting to keep the contents of the text area, but that might not be what they actually want/need.